Finding leap year
I am new to Python and am creating a Python program to check if a year is a leap year or not.
year = int(input())

if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400) == 0:
    print(f"{year} is a leap year.")
else:
    print(f"{year} is not a leap year.")

I created this, but I am not sure if this will work for all use cases or not. However, for some use cases that I have checked it is working fine. Where am I getting it wrong? Any inputs will be appreciated.
I am trying to check if a inputted year is a leap year or not.

The last closing parenthesis doesn't look right.

But it is working fine. Can you try for any use case? @mkrieger1.

I think OP is saying that why this program is passing all the test cases ?? E.g. on Hackerrank, etc.

This is actually correct, but written in a very confusing manner which makes me think it's correct by accident. A clearer way to write the same thing would be year % 4 == 0 and not (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0), which can be simplified into year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0).

Your code is correct.
It is not a good way to write like this as it is very confusing. I just tried to explain why your code is working and passing all test cases.
I will break and try to explain:
def is_leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400) == 0:
      return True
    return False

suppose you enter 1900 which is not a leap year. Your code will execute like this:
1900 % 4 and (1900 % 100 ==0 and year % 400)  == 0
True and (True and 300) == 0
True and 300 == 0
300 ==0

False

For 2000 and other leap years
Similarly you can check for other test cases.
2000 % 4 and (2000 % 100 ==0 and year % 400)  == 0
True and (True and 0) == 0
0 == 0

True

I ran your code on hackerrank


Thanks for the explanation. This is very insightful since it explains how the work undergoes in the backend, or how the compiler works.

if you find the answer useful you can ✔️

A year is a leap year if:
It is divisible by 4, and
If it is divisible by 100, it must also be divisible by 400.
The correct condition should be:
A year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4 and (it is not divisible by 100 or it is divisible by 400).
Please try the below code:
year = int(input("Enter a year: "))

if (year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
    print(f"{year} is a leap year.")
else:
    print(f"{year} is not a leap year.")


try this;
def is_leap_year(year):
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

year = 2024
if is_leap_year(year):
    print(f"{year} is a leap year.")
else:
    print(f"{year} is not a leap year.")


Please refrain from answering simple typo questions. If you made any other changes than move the misplaced parenthesis, explain what you changed and why.
